# Is there a way to name a directory with slash at the end of it ( ex: nameOfDir/ ) and a directory with 2 words and space between them?

Tags: linux, command-line

So, basically I have to name several directories with " / " at the end of the name ( ex: nameOfDir/ ) and also to give some others these kind of names :

example 1:  The Sun

example 2 : Sth & Sth

example 3 : Sth: 'Sth'

How can I can do this? Whenever I write  ' mkdir The Sun' it creates two directories... I am really stuck at this point.

Comment: try with mkdir "The Sun"

Comment: It worked to create a directory with more than one word. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The "/" is a reserved character so you cannot use it as a part of the directory name.

Multiple words and special character like "*", " ", "&" and the like are possible, but I personally recommend against using them as they make names hard to read and easily lead to errors in scripts...